# Connecting to ms-sql server using nodejs

Tags: sql-server, node.js

I'm new to nodejs

I'm trying to connect to my ms-sql database from nodejs

Enviornment:
I'm on 64 bit machine windows 7
nodejs 4.2.2 64-bit
msnodelsql 0.8

I was trying to follow simple example to connect to database

```
var http = require('http');
var sql = require('msnodesql');
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var useTrustedConnection = false;
var conn_str = "Driver={SQL Server Native Client11.0};Server=tcp:yourserver.database.windows.net;" + 
(useTrustedConnection == true ? "Trusted_Connection={Yes};" :     "UID=yourusername;PWD=yourpassword;") + 
"Database={AdventureWorks};"
sql.open(conn_str, function (err, conn) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error opening the connection!");
        return;
    }
    else
        console.log("Successfuly connected");
});
```

the problem is in the

```
var sql = require('msnodesql');
```

I get this error:

```
 module.js:460
 return process.dlopen(module, path._makeLong(filename));
             ^
Error: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

I tried older versions of msnodelsql 0.10 and 0.6 and didnt find a solution on the web for that.

Is there any fix for this issue ? or any other method I can access my database through ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem.
it was stated that it only works with nodejs version 0.8.9

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try another package : [mssql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql)

And you should separate configuration from code, create a config.js file for your configuration make it easier to maintain.

Hope you it can help you.